# Ensure all code on all machines are the same - python mpi

Tags: python, mpi

I can have up to 20 machines in my MPI rings.  How can I automate some sort of checking that all machines are using the same version of their python code?  Is there a way to generate a hash of all the modules/source files in your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to hash the package contents beyond hashing a zip archive of the code. But why not create a local package repository. Have the MPI nodes download the latest version of the package and install it (locally or in a virtualenv if you prefer) at the start of the run? You can always check the package version using setuptools/distribute from within the code as well.

Alternatively, you could use an SCM, updating the code before each run. You can then check scm revision number as a proxy for version.

Personally, the first option feels better as it puts a little discipline in the process (you have to actually build annew package version when appropriate).

Comment: In the end I generated a hash of the main files that are likely to change and sent the hash around to confirm stuff.